# Binding Issues after Upgrading AngularJS 1.1.5 -> 1.2.11

Tags: angularjs, binding, angularjs-directive

So we have a directive we wrote that stopped binding after upgrading from 1.1.5 to 1.2.11.  I don't understand why this would have broken.  Here is the directive code:

```
angular.module("ui.bootstrap.fileupload", []).directive('fileupload', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    scope: {
        prompt: '=',
        changePrompt: '=',
        model: '='
    },
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: '/app/partials/fileupload.html',
    link: function($scope,element,attrs) {
        $(element).fileupload();

        $(element).find("input[type='file']").change( function(event) {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                var fileElement = $(element).find("input[type='file']");
                $scope.model = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < fileElement[0].files.length; i++) {
                    $scope.model.push(fileElement[0].files[i]);
                }
            });
        });
    }
  }
}]);
```

The problem is the line `$scope.model = []`.  That causes the binding to be lost, and now changes to `$scope.model` don't propagate back across the boundary to whatever is bound.  Now this worked quite nicely on 1.1.5.  I couldn't find anything in the changelog or the migration guide that explained this.  Nothing related to binding was in there.

The usage of this directive is as follows:

```
<div fileupload model="uploadFile" prompt="'Select File'" change-prompt="'Change'"></div>
```

If I don't reassign `$scope.model` to a new array.  The two-way binding works.  So what's going on here?

Comment: Is it possible to create a plunker ? I need to see the template and the markup which uses the directive.

Comment: What is the expression you pass to `<myelement model='some.Expression'` Might just be a 'scope as model' instead of 'scope has model' reference issue.

Comment: please check older versions of 1.2.X to see which minor version breaks your code

Comment: I added the markup using the directive.  It'll take me a while to setup a plunkr as it has more dependencies than just that block of code.

Comment: That something like that works would work in the first place seems strange to me (I don't doubt it though, Angular could have some magic in that regard). But how would replacing the property with a new object be propagated to the outside scope, seing as the directive scope is an isolate scope (and, hence, a different object)? Anyways, can you  try setting $scope.model.length = 0 instead of $scope.model = [] to clear the array and see if that works? That should keep the reference and let you update the same array.

Comment: I already have a work around using $scope.model.splice(0,$scope.model.length).  That's not really what I'm interested in.  I want to know why assigning a new value to the model doesn't work because I think my workaround means binding isn't happening, and I'm simply passing by value.